# Looking for a replacement for a potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

I am looking for a replacement for this potentiometer. I did plenty of googling but can't seem to find anything that remotely matches the model.

The numbers on the bottom say: B103-32-8(dot)-KP

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

103 suggests 10 kilohms (across the 2 outer terminals).

Next question is, linear (e.g. for audio "balance") or log (for volume control). If you're not sure, set the control to the halfway position. If it's linear, the resistance will be about 5k from the wiper (centre pin) to each other. If it's logarithmic, expect the wiper to be about 1k from 1 pin and 9k from the other.

As it's very small, power ratings are unlikely to be very critical.

Now it's just a matter of finding a compatible one (same pin spacing, fits in available space, suitable shaft) from any good supplier.

If you can't find an exact match for the shaft, don't worry, just check it's 1/4 inch (6.35mm). Replacements usually have the shaft too long, in soft plastic : a couple of minutes with a hacksaw and file soon fixes that, before you fit it to the PCB.

Comment: ... and hold the shaft in the bench vise and cut the pot off to minimise stress on the pot mechanism. ;^}